# PHP include folder; lots of files vs one file with lots of functions

Tags: php, include

Is there a performance risk if you compare the following two scenarios?

## Folder with 2000 php files

PHP has the ability to select a folder as its include folder. When you then do

```
<?
    include('myfile361.php');
?>
```

php will look into the folder specified in the include_path and include the file, and include that specific file, executing its content.

## One file with 2000 php functions

Lets assume our include file is in the current folder, and our code looks like this:

```
<?
    include('myfile.php');
    my_function_361();
?>
```

## The actual question

I'm wondering, if from a performance point of view there is a significant difference in either options. With 2000 files in a folder, it may take some time to find the right php file, causing overhead. Then again, if I include one file with 2000 functions, php has to go through all these functions too, even though php is efficient enough to skip from the start of the function directly to the end of the function until it finds a match.

Based on this assumption, I would say that the difference is neglectable. Is this true?

Comment: i think lots of files is not so good for speed

Comment: breaking news: disk I/O is slow

Comment: breaking news(2): http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php

Comment: Please do a benchmark and post the result, I would suspect that (with opcache enabled) there would be no significant difference.

Comment: You can also [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) your classes, so the file only needs to be accessed if the class is needed. Unless you want to be like [Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) and have 2000 global functions...

Comment: I do not actually have 2000 functions or files yet. I was hoping someone already had done this so I can base my project around its findings.

Comment: Run a benchmark to be certain of this, but in my experience, calling the filesystem once for a big file, is less ressource expensive than calling the filesystem 2000 times. also, as long as the functions aren't executed right away, it won't have a significant impact. so as far as I know, one include is faster than more includes.

Comment: Please understand, I am not including 2000 files in one go, nor calling 2000 functions. The script could have lots of functions in the future and per script, I may be calling 10 of the 2000 at a time.